# Duration time ignored jquery slideDown

Tags: jquery, slidedown, duration, easing

I have just achieve to slideDown an element with easeInBounce effect but when I put the duration time, it ignores me...

I put

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#hola1" ).slideDown( {easing: "easeInBounce"}, 2899, function() {
        });
    });
```

And I try to put

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#hola1" ).slideDown({
                duration: "3000",
                easing: "easeInBounce"});
    });
```

But it seems the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, be sure that you have the relevant parts of JQuery easing plugin, as the default jquery library does not contain the "easeInBounce" easing option.

Next, you're going to want to make the duration part of the options that you are inserting:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#hola1" ).slideDown( {easing: "easeInBounce", duration: 2899}, function() {
    });
});
```

If you were using `show()` then you could separate them, but even then you have them backwards as duration should come first.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#hola1" ).show(2899, "easeInBounce", function() {
    });
});
```

take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jknn66rh/).

Comment: So the problem is with my jQuery UI?

Comment: Well, are you using JQueryUI? Are you including it? You must make sure that JQueryUI is included to use "easeInBounce", but again, the duration should be inside the `options`, like `easing` is.

Comment: Okey so yes is included because it works but only with his duration time, I try to put inside with the easing and it doesn't work... But I think that it works but not coorrectly because I tried to do with a default easing and I can control the time

Comment: I added a jsfiddle example to my answer. it uses jquery and jqueryui.

Comment: Wow so I have the problem with the jquery script, so I only need jquery and jquery ui?

Comment: Specifically for the `slideDown` effect, using `easeInBounce`, those are the only two libraries necessary, yes.

Comment: I have just added jquery and jquery ui scripts and it doesn't work... I have http://jquery.com/download/ and http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: It's missing JQueryUI. Look in mine, on the left under "External Resources" - you should see `jquery-ui.min.js`. You can add it in yours as well - simply link to `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js`

Comment: Okey I finally achive that works in my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rc2o4ask/6/ But when i try on my phpstorm editor it doesn't work